# Android - Could not open database in Xamarin.forms (SQLite exceptions)

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Sorry if the question is asked before, but i searched very well to handle this problem and i didn't find an answer.

I am handling local database with SQLite in my Xamarin forms project (PCL).

1- The connection is working well in iOS but in android i got this problem
(Could not open database file )

[image]

- I also set "ReadExternalStoarage" and "WriteExternalStoarage" permissions.

2- I used another method of creating the connection path which is :

```
string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "pbcare.db");
```

by this way the exception happened when dealing with the database ...

```
        public bool checkLogin (string email, string password)
        {

            if (DB.Table<User> ().Where (user => user.Email == email && user.Password == password)
                            .FirstOrDefault () != null) { // exception caught here
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

[image]

but the table is there in the database.

Note: this second way create the connection even if the database file doesn't exist !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Android won't be able to use a SQLite database with a file from your local system. The `path` variable has to come from the Android system. The second approach you used to create the path was correct:

```
var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
path = Path.combine(path, 'pbcare.db3');
```

Will create an appropriate file path for the db3 file on Android.

The next issue you reference: `no such table: User` is caused by not creating the table. Before you use the database, you need to create all of the necessary tables.

```
var conn = new SQLiteConnection(path);
conn.CreateTable<User>();
```

If you do this and create the `User` table first, then it should work as expected. There is a more in depth tutorial from Xamarin here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/

Comment: thanks @Dylan-s for responding. So i need to create all tables that i need to use in the app even if it is already created in my database? I tried this, and it didn't create anything into my database. it didn't insert data also. it is like the database is not there. so whatever the app insert or create it is not on my database! i don't know why!

Comment: @Ibrahim Are you using a real device or emulator? Can you use the Android tools to see if the file was created? It kind of sounds like the database file is not being written (I'm not sure why that would happen).

Comment: dear @dylan-s. I am using an emulator. I am sure that the database file is created, but i don't know where? and why it is not dealing with my database? why create a new one? anyway, i used Android tool as you said -first time i know this cool thing- and it is there !! the db file is there containing all data i inserted before! Thanks man. much appreciated

Comment: So now I have to deal with this database that is inside the emulator? is there another way to handle it? cuz i need to add my database file. it contains more information that is needed in my project

Comment: Interesting that your file is created, but the `SQLiteConnection` is not able to find any of the inserted data. Did you insert data using `SQLiteConnection` before trying to query (with the where in your first question)? To your point about creating the table multiple times: that is a bit of a misnomer. `CreateTable` will create a table if it is not present, or do nothing (if it is present). It's good to just always call that when you open the connection.

Comment: Yes i insert data before trying to query. So to understand me, the db file (that is working and the `SQLiteConnection` is dealing with) is created inside the app (in the emulator) not in my project. So whatever data i insert, it is there in the db file (data>data>com.abc.myapp>files>database.db). It is working and everything ok so far. All tables are there with the inserted data. **But** what i need to achieve is that i'm not sure how to add a db file inside the app (). So the `SQLiteConnection` will deal with it and not create a new one. Is it possible? Thanks @dylan-s for bearing with me

Comment: The db file will always be on the device's file system (whether it is an emulator or physical device). You can't change that for SQLite. I don't totally understand your scenario, but it sounds like you want to have seed data. In other words, your database will be pre-populated with data whenever the app is installed. Is that what you're looking for? Otherwise, you might want to share the database between multiple devices (if device 1 inserts something, and then you want to read that on device 2) then SQLite will not support that.

Comment: Yes, I want to Use a pre-populated seed data. Exactly. so inside my app i will deal with it.... Is it possible?

Comment: Xamarin discusses such a process here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_5_using_data_in_an_app/#Using_a_pre-populated_seed_SQLite_database_file. At a high level, you create a database file with the initial data, package it with your application, and write it to the device's file system (if it doesn't exist already) to be used as your file passed to `SQLiteConnection`.